# Binding to IInAppPurchase Google Developer Tutorial

Tags: android, android-studio, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am following this tutorial http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html. I wonder where should I write this code about "binding to IInAppBillingService" . I tried to make a java class inside aidl file(called Service Connection to write the code)but an error pop up said interface or class expected. I little bit confuse right now. Hopefully you guys can help me out.. Thank you :)

You also can check my question on Google+ to see the image
https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/114791428968349268860

[image: Binding]

Comment: Try following the documentation provided here. http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html

Comment: Nice! But how to import Trivial Drive to my existing android app?

Comment: Trivial Drive is only a sample app to explain the usability of IAP API. You can import the project by following the path File > New > Import Sample > Trivial Drive.